# My array skip a sentence everytime there is a comma

Tags: python, numpy

Im sorry if this question had already been asked.

So,my array currently look like this because I use the np.tolist function to an existing array:

```
[['100000.0',
  '200000.0',
  '628400.0',
  '4637400.0',
  '42900.0',
  '916000.0',
  '45230.0',
  '991360.0',
  '423000.0'],
 ['36.0', '12.0', '120.0', '240.0', '90.0', '16.0', '48.0', '99.0', '27.0'],
 ['0.08', '0.1', '0.12', '0.06', '0.07', '0.13', '0.08', '0.08', '0.09'],
 ['20000.0', '', '100000.0', '', '8900.0', '', '4300.0', '', '47200.0']]
```

I want it to look like this. Not arrange vertically for the first list

```
array([['100000.0', '200000.0', '628400.0', '4637400.0', '42900.0', '916000.0', '45230.0', '991360.0', '423000.0'],
       ['36.0', '12.0', '120.0', '240.0', '90.0', '16.0', '48.0', '99.0', '27.0'],
       ['0.08', '0.1', '0.12', '0.06', '0.07', '0.13', '0.08', '0.08', '0.09'],
       ['20000.0', '', '100000.0', '', '8900.0', '', '4300.0', '', '47200.0']], dtype='<U32')
```

do you guys know what is wrong with this array?
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: `np.tolist()` returns a list, not an array.

Comment: If you want to set the dtype in np array, you can pass it as an argument 
`np.array(myarray, dtype='U32')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing what the array CONTAINS with how the array is PRESENTED.  Do you understand that the two outputs you have shown are identical?  When you rely on the default `__str__` handler, you get whatever they thought was best.  If you want the array presented in a certain way, then YOU HAVE TO DO THE FORMATTING.

Comment: Yes, I know that both are identical. I was confuse on why the presentation change after I put np.tolist to my array. I just want it to align nicely without manual formatting. It first showed just like the second format shown above

Comment: _I just want it to align nicely without manual formatting._  Doesn't work that way.  If you want it to align nicely, then you need to format it manually.

Comment: Python doesn't normally print lists with line breaks, are you using a pretty-printer?  It may be putting newlines in the first sublist because it's long. @FastBoi

Comment: I used np.tolist() then it turned out like this. I was thinking about the length as well but i cant find the function to increase the length.